# Is it possible to use HTMX in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm a beginner at working LWC so I could just be doing it wrong, but I can't find anything on the web about it.
I've tried using a static resource and importing via CDN.
Does anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: HTMX is relatively new (or at least recently has gained some traction), and its main use-case (adding reactivity/state management without a bunch of code, DOM manipulation) is already pretty well covered by Lightning Web Components... at least from my PoV. So it's not that surprising you're not finding much info on the topic. Downloading the library and uploading it as a static resource seems to be the way to go, if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

HTMX is not directly compatible with LWC. It is a framework like LWC or Angular, and assumes it has total control over the DOM. Lightning Web Security/Locker Service will not allow it function normally. You'd have to place it in a frame, like Visualforce or a canvas app.

Comment: Thank you! I was just hoping to practice them at the same time.